# Est-ce « humidifier » ou « humecter » ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Sur des instructions, j'ai lu « humecter » comme traduction pour « *moisten* ».
Je m'attendais à lire « humidifier ». Les deux sont-elles correctes ?

Est-ce que « humecter » est un mot Québecois ? J'étais aux US quand j'ai lu ces instructions.

Comment: Il y aurait presque aussi *hydrater* qui pourrait entrer dans la confusion, même si pour les locuteurs avertis le sens n'est qu'apparenté.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Le français a deux mots pour exprimer presque la même chose, leur historique peut expliquer que leur utilisation ne soit pas toujours interchangeable.

« Humidifier » s’inclut dans une famille de mots (humide, humidification, humidité, humidifuge, etc. ) il vient du bas-latin *humificare* (du latin classique *humere*).

« Humecter » est un emprunt savant (XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle)  au latin *humectus* lui-même dérivé du verbe *humere*.

Les deux verbes veulent dire «  rendre humide, mouiller légèrement », mais *Le dictionnaire culturel en langue française* (sld alain Rey)  signale une différence qui me semble non négligeable, à savoir qu'« humidifier », veut dire aussi « rendre plus humide ».
Ceci peut expliquer certaines préférences, voire parfois différences, d'emplois entre les deux.

On humidifie pour des raisons techniques quelque chose qui contient déjà un certain taux  d'humidité. Bien sûr un physicien pourrait dire que tous les corps contiennent déjà un certain taux d'humidité, mais il me semble qu'« humidifier » s'emploie surtout pour l'action d'augmenter  le taux d'H<sub>2</sub>O pour des raisons techniques.

On humidifie l'air pour qu'il soit plus facilement respirable.
On humidifie le linge pour qu'on puisse le repasser plus facilement<sup>1</sup>.
On humidifie le papier peint avant de le décoller du mur.
C'est  « humidifier » qui a donné des dérivés techniques comme « humidifuge », « humidimètre », « humidificateur » etc.

On s'humecte le front quand on a trop chaud.
On s'humecte les lèvres d'une boisson qu'on veut juste goûter, ou en se passant la langue dessus parce qu'elles sont desséchées.
On humecte un timbre ou une enveloppe pour les coller<sup>2</sup>.

« Humecter » est  réservé pour les emplois littéraires :
On a les joues ou les yeux humectés de larmes ; l'herbe ou l'air sont humectés de la fraîcheur matinale.

« Humecter » est aussi réservé aux emplois figurés : on s'humecte d'une ambiance, de l'air du temps.
« S'humecter le gosier » est une expression argotique pour dire « boire une boisson alcoolisée ».

<sub>1. Certaines personnes disent « humecter le linge », mais google renvoie deux fois plus d'entrées pour « humidifier le linge » que pour « humecter le linge ».</sub> 
<sub>2. Éventuellement avec un petit appareil mécanique qu'on appelle un « humecteur », alors que pour l'air on parle d'« humidificateur ».</sub>

Comment: Là ou l'anglais n'en a qu'un ? *Moisten*, *humidify*, *dampen*, *damp*, *moisturize*. Je ne pense pas que ça vaille une remarque.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez juste, merci

Answer (score 4):

Québécois, pour moi humidifier implique une vague brume ou de la vapeur produite volontairement dans l'air (comme le fait un humidificateur).

Humecter implique un objet ou une substance physique sur lequel on applique (ou auquel on mélange) une faible quantité d'eau.

D'une certaine manière, *humidifer* s'oppose pour moi à *assécher*, mais *humecter* peut s'opposer plutôt à *essuyer*.

Answer (score 2):

"Humecter" a un côté précieux.
On humecte (ou s'humecte) toujours légèrement.

Comment: *[S']humecter abondamment* est pourtant une expression très employée, non ? Cela dit, je m'associe à ta remarque car les deux variantes sont, sinon réellement *précieuses*, tout du moins ampoulées (un peu comme le terme *ampoulé*).

Answer (score 1):

Ils sont synonymes : *mouiller légèrement, superficiellement*

Il sont interchangeables, avec peut-être une nuance médicale ou corporelle pour *humecter* où l'on *mouille* légèrement un organe :

> Humectez la peau avant de ...

alors que l'on *humidifie*, on rend humide un objet... qui devient *mouillé*.

Answer (score 0):

Humecter est un synonyme correct d'*humidifier*.

Il est utilisé entre autres dans l'expression *s'humecter les lèvres*.